# linklist and memory issues

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, data-mining, linked-lists

I have a doubly link-list like this

```
typedef struct Record
{
   int i;
   Record* next;
   Record* prev;
}Record;
```

I have over 5 trillions of records that I need to handle, now that I need to retrieve all of them and sort them out.
If its size was small, I could borrow stl's vector or list to do the job but now that it is too huge, I have no idea how to save the object data before sorting is performed

my function prototype

```
void sortRec(Record**recToSort,bool bASC){}
```

Comment: Not sure this is in scope here.

Comment: Where are the records currently saved? Are they all in memory? In disk?

Comment: Use the [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) if your data doesn't fit into your memory.

Answer (score 2):

You should also have a look at [External Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithms. This is another book on the subject [Algorithms and Data Structures for External Memory](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jsv/Papers/Vit.IO_book.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the records are really stored in the disk, you can use radix sort. Divide you integer into bytes, and start with the lower-order byte. Open 256 new files, and start going over your database in order, sorting the files according to the lower-order byte. Then do it again with the next byte, this time reading your 256 files in order.

If memory is not at a premium, you could always allocate an array - that will actually be more memory-efficient than a linked list. (Why would you use a linked list for such a big array anyhow? The overhead is 200%.)

Comment: Thank you a lot, all records are saved in database and in xml file too

Answer (score 1):

You can merge-sort a list in memory.

Let split(a)->(b,c) be a function that splits the list a so that approximately half the number of elements go into b and the rest goes into c. Time for split should be T(n).

Let merge(a,b)->c be a function that merges the two ordered list a and b into an ordered list c. Time for merge should be T(n).

Sorting can then be performed in O(n*log(n)):

```
def sort(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a
    b, c = split(a)
    return merge(sort(b), sort(c))
```